# How to check condition for observations that belong to a specific category in R?

Tags: r, twitter

I’m sorry if the question is confusing, I couldn’t find a better way to express it.

I have a dataset with tweets, user ids and dates when the tweets were created.

```
userid            tweet         date
1132622143        bla bla       2014-04-23
1132622143        bla bla       2014-05-23
1132622143        ...           ...
1132622143
1132622145
```

I want to make a subset of this dataset that contains data for users who posted something on Twitter recently, say in May or later, so for users who have at least one tweet where   date > 2014-05-01 (I want to have all recent and old tweets for these active users in my new dataset).

I think I need to create a function that will say something like this:

```
for each distinct userid
    find all rows with same userid value and put them in a list
    for each row in a list
        if there exists a row where date>2014-05-01
    select all rows for this userid
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct logic and if yes, how to actually program this. I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`ave` could be of use here.

Here's a generalization of your problem, which you can hopefully extend to your actual data.

First, some sample data. I'm assuming you know how to convert your "date" variable to an actual time/date variable.

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4),
  text = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "a"),
  time = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1)
)
```

With `ave`, you can create a logical vector by group. Here, we check to see if any "time" is greater than or equal to 4 within each set of "id"s. If there are any, it returns `TRUE` for all the rows of that "id".

That information can be used directly to extract just those relevant rows.

```
as.logical(with(mydf, ave(time, id, FUN = function(x) any(x > 4))))
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
mydf[as.logical(with(mydf, ave(time, id, FUN = function(x) any(x > 4)))), ]
#    id text time
# 4   2    a    2
# 5   2    b    3
# 6   2    c    4
# 7   2    d    4
# 8   2    e    5
# 9   3    a    3
# 10  3    b    5
# 11  3    c    5
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Ananda. This is exactly what I need, however, I still have a small problem with date comparison. I've set my date for comparison as:     targetData <- as.Date("2014-03-01")   and I made sure my column with dates is in "date" format. My code looks like this:    recent<- data[as.logical(with(data, ave(dates, userid, FUN = function(x) any(x > targetData)))), ]   and I'm getting an error: Error in as.Date.default(value) : do not know how to convert 'value' to class "Date"    Do you have any advice about that?

Comment: I solved it, I need to add as.numeric: as.logical(with(mydf, ave(as.numeric(date), id, FUN = function(x) any (x > d1)))).